# Centered <div> box colliding with left and right aligned <div> boxes above

Tags: html, css, alignment

I've been making a project after learning HTML and CSS (haven't learned JavaScript yet, but I'm getting to it soon), and I've run into a slight problem.

I'm trying to have two div boxes (left and right aligned respectively, both 45% width), and then have a 45% width centered div box below it. It technically works, but the problem is while the centered div box *is* below the left and right boxes, only half of it is. The other half pours into the edges of the left and right boxes above.

[image: for further clarification]

This is what my HTML code looks like for these 3 boxes:

```
    <div class="left-align">
        <p class="medium-font">
            This box is <b>left-aligned</b>, so it'll be much less wide than other boxes.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="right-align">
        <p class="medium-font">
            This is box <b>right-aligned</b>, so it'll also be much less wide, however it's on the right now.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="center-align medium-font dotted-border bg-dkred">
        <form>
            <span>Form test thing i dunno</span>
            <p>Favorite gemstone:</p>
            <input type="text" name="fav-gem" value=""><br/>
        </form>
    </div>
```

And my CSS code for the alignments:

```
div.right-align
{
    width:45%;
    float:right;
}

div.left-align
{
    width:45%;
    float:left;
}

div.center-align
{
    width:45%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

I tried putting the two left and right boxes in their own  element, however that didn't make any difference.

Any help is appreciated, I can provide more info if you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have float element, therefore it is ignored by 3rd div (the one below), just add `clear: both` to 3rd div to not allowed float element at both side of this element.

> The clear CSS property specifies whether an element can be next to floating elements that precede it or **must be moved down (cleared)** below them. The clear property applies to both floating and non-floating elements.
>   Example:
>
> [image]
>
> REF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clear

```css
div.right-align {
  width: 45%;
  float: right;
  background: red;
}

div.left-align {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  background: aqua;
}

div.center-align {
  width: 45%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: green;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-align">
  <p class="medium-font">
    This box is <b>left-aligned</b>, so it'll also be much less wide, however it's on the left now.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="right-align">
  <p class="medium-font">
    This is box <b>right-aligned</b>, so it'll also be much less wide, however it's on the right now.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="center-align medium-font dotted-border bg-dkred">
  <form>
    <span>Form test thing i dunno</span>
    <p>Favorite gemstone:</p>
    <input type="text" name="fav-gem" value=""><br/>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Only uses up one extra line of code, too, which is nice.